# Get open app (foreground) name swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a time tracker. So I need to know an information about user activity. Is it possible to get the name of an app, which user is using at the moment in iOS with Swift?

Comment: Not permitted by Apple.

Comment: You are asking how to implement the core feature of your app...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that because iOS doesn't allow it.